# ranking on same date sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Table 1:
id  |       date      | value
1    15/04/2013 15:45    1
1    15/04/2013 15:55    1
2    16/04/2013 15:45    2
2    16/04/2013 15:55    2
3    17/04/2013 15:25    3
3    17/04/2013 15:35    3
```

After using query

```
Select * 
from (
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by id, date ORDER BY date DESC) from table X
) A
```

It RANKS all the rows properly except the rows which appear on same day but different times.

In other words i want to write sql which can rank on date and then on its time.

Comment: Can you show what your expected output is? I don't understand your description.

Comment: Isn't that done just by removing the partition on date? Or are you after 2 rank values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM (
    SELECT x.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date)) ORDER BY date DESC) rownum
      FROM table1 x
) A
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |                         DATE | VALUE | ROWNUM |
------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | April, 15 2013 15:55:00+0000 |     1 |      1 |
|  1 | April, 15 2013 15:45:00+0000 |     1 |      2 |
|  2 | April, 16 2013 15:55:00+0000 |     2 |      1 |
|  2 | April, 16 2013 15:45:00+0000 |     2 |      2 |
|  3 | April, 17 2013 15:35:00+0000 |     3 |      1 |
|  3 | April, 17 2013 15:25:00+0000 |     3 |      2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/baec9/6)** demo

Comment: However Peter the i tried removing and just run it using DateDIFF alone , i still get the proper ranking.  But anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

try

```
order by convert(datetime, date, 103) DESC
```